# How to add couchbase index replicate without deleting it

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have in my environment one secondary index (without replication) and I want to know how do I create the replicates without dropping the index?

I don't want to delete the index and recreate it with the replicates because I am not using the primary index, hence the constraint.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not possible to alter the index replicat count with your Couchbase version:

You should :

1. Create the same index with different name (this time replicated)
2. Drop the index not replicated after the creation of the first index.

reference :

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/alterindex.html

Answer (score 4):

Upcoming 6.50 release you can modify index replication count (Example 4) https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/alterindex.html

Another alternative to @Lho Ben solution (CE version) is (9. Duplicate Indexes) described here https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/

Answer (score 2):

You can create equivalent indexes with right number of replica count to ensure scans continue to work and drop older index. We support altering replica count through ALTER INDEX in enterprise edition.